# Computing the name of the month

Tags: java, beginner, datetime

I created the following program that transforms a numerical month into the corresponding textual month. I initially calculated the `starPoint` and `endPoint` in the class constructor; then I changed that calculation to the `getName` method. Which is a better option? Calculating in the class constructor, or in a separate method like shown in the code?

```
/**
 * Created by Robert Holland on 25/11/2016.
 *
 * A class that accepts a number and calculates
 * the corresponding month. Once the month has
 * been calculated it will then be returned.
 *
 */

public class Month
{
    public static final String MONTHS = "January   " + "February  " + "March     " +
                                        "April     " + "May       " + "June      " +
                                        "July      " + "August    " + "September " +
                                        "October   " + "November  " + "December  ";
    private int monthNumber;

    //Construct a month class that has a value equal to the numerical month
    //@param uMonthNumber the number of the month to find the correspondance.
    public Month(int uMonthNumber)
    {
        monthNumber = uMonthNumber;
    }

    //Determine the name that corresponds to the month number.
    //@return month the name of the corresponding month.
    public String getName()
    {
        String month;
        int startPoint;
        int endPoint;

        endPoint = monthNumber * 10;
        startPoint = endPoint - 10;
        month = MONTHS.substring(startPoint, endPoint);

        return month;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[This exists already](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html):

It's not the prettiest to use but it's there.

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Month month = Month.of(2);
        System.out.printf("%s", month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, new Locale("en")));
        // outputs:
        // February
    }
}
```

Don't re-write code that's in your standard libraries :)

Comment: `Month.of(2);` is also [`Month.FEBRUARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#FEBRUARY), which is prettier. Also `new Locale("en")` could be replaced with [`Locale.ENGLISH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ENGLISH). Avoids creating objects (since it reuses a constant), and is more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense why you're putting all 12 strings into a single `String` rather than an array.

You may also wish to return `month.trim()` to get rid of the extra whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

> To short as an answer so leaving as a comment: Why not make `getName()` the `toString()` for your class? Also, concatenating 12 strings together only to keep applying `String.substring(int, int)` every time you want to get the name sounds a little counterintuitive IMHO...
>
> ([from my comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148112/computing-the-name-of-the-month#comment278560_148112))

The main advantage of using `toString()` is so that the [*textual representation*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) is available for use by users of your class easily.

Getting to the crux of your question (which I have also somewhat answered above):

> Which is a better option? Calculating in the class constructor, or in a separate method like shown in the code?

My advice is that if there's a variable on your class that should be *immutable* the moment an object is instantiated, it should be done in the class constructor. That's because you can declare the variable as `final` and you can reliably use it within your class knowing that it cannot be changed. Your `Month` class seems like a good example of this. :)

A suggestion (using your coding style):

```
public class Month
{
    private final int monthNumber;
    private final String monthName;

    public Month(int monthNumber)
    {
        this.monthNumber = monthNumber;
        this.monthName = generateName(monthNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return monthName;
    }

    private static generateName(int monthNumber)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```